# Instagram Register HttpWebRegister

Tags: vb.net, cookies, httpwebrequest, instagram

I want to make a method to create an Instagram, but I can't to figure out how to get the cookie automatically

My old method :

```
Function register()

    Dim postData As String = "email=" & EmailBox.Text + "@gmail.com" & "&password=" & PassBox.Text & "&username=" & UserBox.Text & "&first_name=" & NameBox.Text
    Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
    Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)

    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/web_create_ajax/"), HttpWebRequest)
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.KeepAlive = True
            request.Headers.Add("X-CSRFToken", "q4NBIiEDDiPwGliNk6xxxxW9IooCHm")
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.Headers.Add("X-Instagram-AJAX", "1")
    request.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
    request.Headers.Add("Cookie", "mid=WZWf8QALxxxxcWsM-P1hm5F; csrftoken=q4NBIiEDDixxxxZrW9IooCHm; rur=FTW; ig_vw=16; ig_pr=1; ig_vh=4")

    request.Referer = "https://www.instagram.com/"
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1"
    request.ContentLength = byteData.Length

    Dim requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    requestStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
    requestStream.Close()

    Dim responseS As HttpWebResponse
    responseS = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

    Dim Reader As New StreamReader(responseS.GetResponseStream())
    Dim thepage As String = Reader.ReadToEnd
    If thepage.Contains("This username isn't available. Please try another") Then
        Label6.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed
        Label6.Text = UserBox.Text + "Has been fail register !!"
    Else
        Label6.ForeColor = Color.LightGreen
        Label6.Text = UserBox.Text + "Has been successfully register !!"
    End If
    TextBox1.Text = thepage
End Function
```

How can I get the cookie automatically?

Answer (score 0):

there you go. This is an sample for login in to ASP.NET MVC website. Look for Cookiejar to retreive them.

```
   Dim tclient As HttpClient
     Dim cookiejar As New CookieContainer
            cookiejar = handler.CookieContainer
            Dim xResponse As HttpResponseMessage = Await (tclient.GetAsync(BaseAddress & LoginUrl))
            Dim xcookies As CookieCollection = cookiejar.GetCookies(New Uri(BaseAddress & LoginUrl))
            For Each tCookie As Cookie In xcookies
                If tCookie.Name = "__RequestVerificationToken" Then vCookie = tCookie : VerificationToken = tCookie.Value : Exit For
            Next

            Dim body As String = Await (xResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())
            Dim htdoc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
            htdoc.LoadHtml(body)
            Dim xxdoc As HtmlNode = htdoc.GetElementbyId("loginform")
            For Each xnodes As HtmlNode In xxdoc.Elements("input")
                If xnodes.Attributes(0).Value = "__RequestVerificationToken" Then
                    FormValidationToken = xnodes.Attributes(2).Value
                End If
            Next
```